Analogy of Euler-Lagrange-equation and Continuity equation
It seems to me that there is a link between the continuity equation
$$\nabla\rho u + \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = 0$$
and the Euler-Lagrange equation for Lagrangian mechanics
$$\nabla_q  L - \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\nabla_\dot{q} L = 0.$$
Is it possible to formulate the Euler-Lagrange formula in dependence of a "Lagrangian density" that equates the continuity equation for this density to the Euler-Lagrange equation? How are these formula linked, how do they differ?

The continuity equation term is divergence $\sum_k \partial_k(ru_k)$, the Euler-Lagrange equation term is just a single derivative $\partial L/\partial q_k$.

Except for similarity of graphics, they have nothing in common.
The first equation is the triviality, that a flow of an incompressible fluid  passing over the surface into and out of  a small fixed volume $\mathrm{d}V$ in space equals the production or absorption in  that volume per time interval $\mathrm{d}t$.
The second equation say that a particle moving in field of rotation free force, that has a potential function of work line integrals, is accelerated in direction and strength with that force as the gradient of the potential function.
What is so fascinating is the independece of the Lagrangian equations of motion w.r.t. any change of variables, including non-potential forces induced by curvilinear or time-dependent coordinate functions.
In these cases the Lagrangian equations produce the accelerations as Christoffel affine tensor forces, a direct way to General Relativity.
There is of course the canonical form of mechanics in momentum and position variables.
And in fact, this formulation with a Hamiltonian $H=T+V$, the sum of kinetic energy $T$ and the potential $V$
$$\partial_t x = \nabla_p H,  \quad  \partial_t p = -\nabla H$$
yields Liouvilles continuity equation for the flow of any volume $$\prod_i \mathrm{d}p_i\wedge \mathrm{d}x_i$$
in phase space.
But this flow decribes the time evolution of statistical densitities, given by the densitity of the start values $$\rho\left(p(0),x(0)\right)\mapsto \rho\left(p\left(t,p(0),x(0)\right),x\left(t,p(0),x(0)\right)\right)$$
of interacting particles obeying their mechanical equations of motion in a deterministic way.
The diffusion equation on the other hand describes independent free particles performing a Brownian motion under the influence of white noise displacement scaled per time interval $\mathrm{d}t$ by  $\sqrt{\mathrm{d}t}$, no determinism, pure chaos.
There has been 100 years of reseach to unite both views, but the deterministic Hamiltonian flow filling a chaotically evolving volume over endless times and diffusion filling smooth volumes with an analytical smooth density in an instant of time seem to represent very different concepts.
